# How to get user details from Websphere UserRegistry

Tags: java, websphere

How to fetch the user's other details from AD after logging into the application using LDAP registry configured in WebSphere server. I have Java EE application, which is using the single sign on. I want to get the other details like email, office location of the user which is configured in Active Directory. How do I get that?

```
        // Retrieves the default InitialContext for this server.
        javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();

        // Retrieves the local UserRegistry object.
        com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry reg = (com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry) ctx
                .lookup("UserRegistry");
```

From this registry, is there chance to get it?

Answer (score 2):

In WebSphere Application Server you can access User Registry information -and modify it- thorugh the [Virtual Member Manager](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Virtual%20Member%20Manager) componente an its API.

There's plenty of documentation and samples on [IBM Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/userregistry.html). From there, the code snippet to get the properties of an entity like a user:

```
DataObject root = SDOHelper.createRootDataObject();
DataObject entity = SDOHelper.createEntityDataObject(root, null, DO_PERSON_ACCOUNT);
entity.createDataObject(DO_IDENTIFIER).set(PROP_UNIQUE_NAME, 
                             "uid=SalesManager,cn=users,dc=yourco,dc=com");
DataObject propCtrl = SDOHelper.createControlDataObject(root, null, DO_PROPERTY_CONTROL);           
propCtrl.getList(PROP_PROPERTIES).add("sn");
propCtrl.getList(PROP_PROPERTIES).add("uid");
propCtrl.getList(PROP_PROPERTIES).add("cn");
propCtrl.getList(PROP_PROPERTIES).add("telephoneNumber");
propCtrl.getList(PROP_PROPERTIES).add("createTimestamp");

root = service.get(root);
```

To get the service instance that communicates with the registry you need first to execute the [Programming Prerequisites](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/programmingprereq.html) of the API. I stringly suggest you to review the Infocenter documentation.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the details without virtual member manager? because wer can't go and edit the existing system configuration. We are not provided much preveliges.

Comment: You can connect using an external API: I've tried Spring LDAP and works great

Comment: Hi carlos, Please share me Spring LDAP implementations to query WebSphere file based repository.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about exactly that question:

http://veithen.github.io/2012/12/13/retrieving-custom-user-attributes-from.html

Note that the conclusion is compatible with what Carlos wrote: you have to use VMM.